# How does this AWK command preserve array element order?

Tags: arrays, awk

Here's a list of RGB values from a file called 'colors.txt'

```
255 222 0  
101 153 255  
255 153 0  
13  112 84  
13  112 84  
255 222 0  
13  112 84  
9   112 84
```

I can use an awk array to get the 5 unique RGB combinations from the file with

```
awk '{arr[($1","$2","$3)]} END {for (i in arr) print i}' colors.txt
```

This gives:

```
9,112,84  
255,222,0  
13,112,84  
255,153,0  
101,153,255
```

Notice that these aren't in the order they were in the input file. However, this command

```
awk 'arr[($1","$2","$3)]++==0 {print ($1","$2","$3)}' colors.txt

255,222,0  
101,153,255  
255,153,0  
13,112,84  
9,112,84
```

preserves the order. How exactly does this work? I found the [second command version here](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.awk/printing-unique-values-in-4th-field/434766).

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, one could combine it into an awkish:

```
awk '!A[$1=$1,$2,$3]++' OFS=, file
```

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
awk '{arr[($1","$2","$3)]} END {for (i in arr) print i}' colors.txt
```

prints the hash after you read all the input, and since hash keys do not preserve the order the output is quite arbitrary.

This command:

```
awk 'arr[($1","$2","$3)]++==0 {print ($1","$2","$3)}' colors.txt
```

Checks if the same combination was previously printed using a hash, however, it immediately prints the input if `arr[($1","$2","$3)]` is zero. So, there is no order preservation. It is more like immediate printing.

Answer (score 4):

*perreal* has explained why the order is preserved, I wanted to touch on some of the finer points of this idiom:

- If only one array occurs in the script, I tend to use the name `hash` or `h` for it to remind myself of its type.
- Comma separated array subscripts already work as expected in `gawk` and `nawk`, i.e. `h[$1,$2,$3]` becomes `h[$1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3]`. The default value of `SUBSEP` is `\034` or `0x1c`.
- I find `!h[...]++` more readable than `h[...]++==0`, maybe that's just me.
- I prefer using `OFS` over explicit printing, i.e. `$1=$1; print` over `print ($1","$2","$3)`.

All these taken together:

```
awk '!h[$1,$2,$3]++ { $1=$1; print }' OFS=',' colors.txt
```

Comment: In that situation I name my array "seen" to represent what it's being used for (i.e. a test of whether or not the index has been seen before) rather than "hash" representing how it's stored. So I'd use `!seen[$1,$2,$3]++` but nbd either way. +1 for !array[index]++ and use of OFS.